# Separate Worker Server for Delayed Job Using Capistrano on Linode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, delayed-job

I have an app that heavily relies on background processing and I would like to have the delayed_job workers on a separate Linode instance for performance reasons. I have found [this really helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621817/rails-can-i-run-backgrounds-jobs-in-a-different-server/4621886) about being able to run DJ workers on a different server without having to boot Apache and it looks like that's how I'll be setting things up.

My question is how do I go about configuring Capistrano to deploy my app to both servers, only running the actual web facing end from one, and using the other one for DJ? Would I do something like this?

```
role :web, "domain.com"
role :app, "domain.com", "workers.domain.com"
role :db,  "domain.com", :primary => true
```

Comment: Check out these two questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210715/before-after-hooks-for-only-particular-roles-for-library-provided-recipes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621817/rails-can-i-run-backgrounds-jobs-in-a-different-server

Answer (score 1):

You can set a separate server role for delayed jobs adding this to your recipe:

```
set :delayed_job_server_role, :utility
```

Then, attach this role to your worker (utility) server:

```
role :web, "domain.com"
role :app, "domain.com"
role :db,  "domain.com", :primary => true
role :utility, "workers.domain.com"
```

For more info:
https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Rails-3-and-Capistrano