# Invoke delayed_job capistrano tasks only on specific servers

Tags: ruby, capistrano, delayed-job

I have a dedicated server for delayed_job tasks. I want to start, stop, and restart delayed_job workers on **only** this server. I am using the capistrano recipes provided by delayed_job.

When I only had 1 server, this was my config:

```
before "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:stop"
after  "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:start"

after "deploy:stop",    "delayed_job:stop"
after "deploy:start",   "delayed_job:start"
```

Now I want to have those hooks **only** apply to a separate delayed_job server (`role :delayed_job <ip address>`). Is this possible to do elegantly? Do I have to wrap each delayed_job tasks in a meta task? Or write my own tasks and not use the ones provided by delayed job?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you define a task in Capistrano you can restrict the execution of the task to specific role(s). The way you do this is by passing the `:role` option.

It seems the [default delayed_job Capistrano recipe](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/recipes.rb) does this.

```
desc "Stop the delayed_job process"
task :stop, :roles => lambda { roles } do
  run "cd #{current_path};#{rails_env} script/delayed_job stop"
end
```

According to the source code, the task fetches the list of roles from the `:delayed_job_server_role` configuration variable.

Back to your problem, to narrow the execution of the tasks to a specific group of servers, define a new role (for example worker) in your `deploy.rb`

```
role :worker, "192.168.1.1" # Assign the IP of your machine
```

Then set the `:delayed_job_server_role` to that name

```
set :delayed_job_server_role, :worker
```

That's all. Now the tasks will be executed, but only to the servers listed in the `:worker` role.

Comment: Yay! I am so happy. (and I'll go document that flag on their wiki...)